# Passing string from Python as a parameter to a Go function in a shared object

Tags: python, string, go, shared-objects

I'm trying to call the below `MakeQuery(query string)` function by passing the string from Python using `ctypes` module.

It works when I call it from Python as a function shared object with hardcoded arguments from `Works()` in Go:

```
//export Works
func Works() {
    newMod := MakeQuery(`SELECT TOP 3 NodeID FROM NCM.ConfigArchive`)
    fmt.Println(newMod)
}

// Query db connection and return results as map
//export MakeQuery
func MakeQuery(query string) []map[string]interface {} {...}
```

According to some web tutorials, I need to convert it as such:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./test.so")
query = "SELECT TOP 3 NodeID FROM NCM.ConfigArchive"
b_query = query.encode('utf-8')
lib.MakeQuery.argtypes = [c_char_p]
print lib.MakeQuery(b_query)
```

But it doesn't work due to some string type conversion error:

```
&{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[1602] Content-Type:
[application/json] Date:[Sat, 18 May 2019 12:48:54 GMT] Server:[Microsoft-
HTTPAPI/2.0]] 0xc00009a1c0 1602 [] false false map[] 0xc000104000 0xc0001a8000}
```

Would be a great help if someone can point me to the direction to convert Python's string type into Go in some way.

Comment: Hi, so you can grpc. A grpc server in Golang and its client in python. You can pass strings from Python to Golang-based server, make a query and return the result to Python as maps.